# ¿Cuál es mi error al copilar el documento desde swave?

Tags: r, rstudio

resulta que quiero copilar un documento desde swave en r, con sus respectivas librerias xtable y knitr, y con los comandos de LateX, pero cuando voy a copilar me sale el siguiente error.

.....en la Writing to file EJEMPLO12020.tex

```
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on 'EJEMPLO12020.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on EJEMPLO12020.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/Jennifer/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)
```

Tengo algo mal configurado?? o que debo hacer, mil gracias.

Comment: Bienvenida jennifer a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Es muy poca la información del problema como para poder ayudarte, te sugiero 1) ubica físicamente el archivo tex que te genera R 2) Abre una línea de comandos o la terminal de Rstudio y ejecuta `pdflatex EJEMPLO12020.tex`, y finalmente agrega la salida de esto a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No sé con certeza cuál sea la causa exacta pero puedes probar una de estas opciones:

1. Revisa que el path de R apunte a la instalación correcta de miktex (puedes seguir las instrucciones en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33670021/236345) de SO).
   Para validar este caso, puedes usar el archivo *environment* de R para cambiar la variable PATH para R solamente. Revisa `?Startup` en R para más detalles de este proceso. Sigue estos pasos:

   - En R, revisa la salida de `Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON")`. Esto retorna la ruta absoluta a un archivo existente de *environment*, que usualmente estará vacío. Si el archivo existe, salta al paso 3 más abajo.
   - Si el paso anterior no retorna una ruta, crea un archivo `Renviron.site` en la carpeta `R_HOME/etc` donde `R_HOME` es la ruta que retorna `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")`.
   - Añade una línea al archivo de *environment* que contenga: `PATH=C:\\full\\path\\to\\the\\folder\\with\\pdflatex;"${PATH}"` (las comillas son importantes!)
   - Reinicia R y revisa que `Sys.getenv("PATH")` y `Sys.which("pdflatex")` retornen las rutas correctas.
2. Es posible que usar pdftex desde R Studio no instale todas las dependencias requeridas y por ello falle el proceso. En [esta respuesta](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511813/95812) sugieren usar un archivo tex de prueba para garantizar que corra, genere todos los archivos intermedios `sty` y después ejecute correctamente cualquier tex que quieras compilar.

Fuente: [foro tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429757/pdflatex-problem-with-rstudio)